# Auto-fixing transform after enabling/disabling child of constraint

Tags: animation, scripting, keyframes, drivers, bone.constraints

I don’t have a particularly specific problem, rather a common one and I have never seen anyone trying to solve it in this way.
Is there a way to automate the change in bone/object position when the child of constraint is turned off?
To make it clear, now in order to leave the bone in the position where it is with the modifier turned on, you need to click the “disable and keep transform” button.

[image: The button for keeping tranform]

What I want (roughly) is for us to create a keyframe with perhaps a driver that will automatically set positions for the bone where the modifier influence is 0.
For what? I'm an animator and every time I decide to change something in an animation where this modifier is needed, I have to do the same operation many times, so creating this method will make life easier for many animators and allow them to focus on the creative process rather than observing positions with a modifier.

As i know, there no drivers for keyframes, but maybe is there another way for this?

Comment: I'm not sure how this Disable and Keep Transform option works, you could create a keyframe > Visual Location, Rotation & Scale for the child object at the same frame where the Influence is keyed at 0, then keyframe the Influence at 0 (don't pay attention to the fact that the child will move, it won't once animated), but you probably already know it? Also there's an addon called Dynamic Parent but it just automatically creates the constraints and keyframes: https://github.com/romanvolodin/dynamic_parent